# Angular2 animation rotate direction?

Tags: angular, css-animations

I have a menu icon within Angular2, which should always rotates clockwise.
When show, it should rotates from -360 degree to -180 degree.
When hide, it should rotates from -180 degree to 0 degree.

But with this animation settings it rotates counterclockwise with transition state 'hide' to 'show'. How can I make it rotate clockwise?

```js
export const MenuButtonAnimation = trigger('menuState', [
        state('hide', style({ transform: 'rotate(0)' })),
        state('show', style({ transform: 'rotate(-180deg)' })),
        transition('hide => show', animate('350ms ease-out')),
        transition('show => hide', animate('350ms ease-in'))
    ]);
```

Answer (score 3):

Add style `{ transform: 'rotate(-360deg)' }` for 'hide => show', to properly hint browser to treat 0 deg as -360 deg (although they are logically the same).

```js
export const MenuButtonAnimation = trigger('menuState', [
        state('hide', style({ transform: 'rotate(0)' })),
        state('show', style({ transform: 'rotate(-180deg)' })),
        transition('hide => show', [style({transform: 'rotate(-360deg)'}), animate('350ms ease-out')]),
        transition('show => hide', animate('350ms ease-in'))
    ]);
```